# Having multiple variations of basic css classes( I.E h1, h2, p)

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a static page I created for my WordPress themes frontpage and now I want to add a custom blog. I want the blog to be a little different and have different headings, paragraph attributes etc. Would I be able to just add an extra name to distinguish between the front pages classes and the blogs classes so I can use them?

For instance:

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
border:0;
font-size:100%;
font:inherit;
vertical-align:baseline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Would look like this :

```
blog html,blog body,blog div,blog span,blog applet,blog object,blog iframe,blog h1,blog h2,blog h3,blog h4,blog h5,blog h6,blog p {
border:0;
font-size:100%;
font:inherit;
vertical-align:baseline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Than when calling it I would do this?

```
<blog h1>This is heading 1</blog h1>
```

Or would I need to call it like a normal class in this situation? As such:

```
<div class="blog h1">This is a test</div>
```

Comment: You could just call a separate CSS file on your blog that overrides or adds any properties you want, no need for an extra selector

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways is to use blog for ID and then define your classes:

```
#blog .h1{
border:0;
font-size:100%;
font:inherit;
vertical-align:baseline;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

<div id="blog" class="h1">This is a test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If they are different pages (as I suspect due to the different "body" styling) can't you simply use totally separate CSS files (one for "front pages", one for "blog pages)?

2) If you prefer syntax similar to what you suggested, note a selector such as ".blog span" means "an element of type span, that is a descendant of a BLOG container"
Just note the "dot"

```
.blog span {border:...}

<div class="blog">
<span>hello</span>
</div>
```